# how to repeat line numbers in a file separated by an empty line

Tags: line-numbers

I want to restart the counting with 1 where ever there is an emptyline in my file.

My file is like this:
cat test.txt

333|111|222|333|
222|111|333|222|

I am using cat test.txt | sed 's/|/\n/g' | nl
output:
1  333
2  111
3  222
4  333

5  222
6  111
7  333

What i want is that after empty line the counting again start from 1.
desired output:
1  333
2  111
3  222
4  333

1  222
2  111
3  333

please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is quite trivial in 'awk', or one of its clones gawk, nawk.

Create a script linerecount.awk with content:

```
/^$/ { lineno=0; next}
     { print ++lineno, $0}
```

First line obviously resets the linenumber and skips to next line.
Second line increments linenumber, prints it, prints line.

Apply with gawk -f linerecount.awk to whatever you want.

Input:

```
$ cat input.txt
First line
Second line
Third line

Second part, First line
Second line
Third line

Final part, First line
Second line
```

Output:

```
$ gawk -f linerecount.awk < input.txt
1 First line
2 Second line
3 Third line
1 Second part, First line
2 Second line
3 Third line
1 Final part, First line
2 Second line
```

Comment: can i use nl command to achieve it?

Comment: You would still need awk to partition the file.

Comment: peter please be specific. I am still unable to conceive your answer

Comment: PS. I tried using nl, using blank line as section delimiter, but it did not restart numbering, it just stopped?!